# Pandas Date Functionality: Extracting Period Index information as String

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a dataframe(df_qtr) in the following format:

```
Index      2008Q4     2009Q1    2009Q2 
 Ex       85833.33   85433.33   85766.66
 Kc      153200.00  150533.33  149666.66
 Al       83766.66   84200.00   84333.33
 Jk      107933.33  113600.00  115366.66
 Ar      151200.00  147133.33  143900.00
 Ax      139300.00  137333.33  132700.00
```

The column headers are **period indexes** created by consolidating Monthly data (dates were column headers) using the following code:

`In[1]: df_qtr = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='q'), axis=1).mean()`

I would like to extract the **column headers as strings** as:

`Out[1]: ['2008Q4', '2009Q1', '2009Q2']`

The closest I have come is converting it back to timestamp and then string:

```
 In[2]: list(df_qtr.columns.to_datetime().astype(str))
 Out[2]: Index(['2008-10-01', '2009-01-01', '2009-04-01']
```

But the same does not work with a Period Index and I get the following error:

`ValueError: Cannot cast PeriodIndex to dtype <U0`

I can convert the list above to a Period Index again and then convert it to string but isn't there an easier workaround to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I found an answer while going through the docs. The function **datetime.strftime()** can be used for this:

```
In[3]: df_qtr.columns.strftime('%YQ%q')
Out[3]: array(['2008Q4', '2009Q1', '2009Q2'], dtype='<U6')
```

Turns out it can be used with datetime, timestamp and period indexes. To know more read here: [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)